# Можно ли с помощью getopt распарсить аргументы без - и --?

Tags: c++, linux, c

Можно ли с помощью getopt  распарсить аргументы без -   и -- ? Тоесть, могу ли я с помощью getopt корректно распарсить следующие пример ?

```
program param1 -p2 --param2
```

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/55665/

Comment: Нет. Такие аргументы будут передвинуты в конец `argv[]`. После окончания разбора они начинаются с `argv[optind]`. / Это описано в [man 3 getopt](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html)